# PHP script not capturing form values

Tags: php, forms, email

I have the following html code for a simple contact form.

```
<form action="requestdate.php" class="unit-66">
    <fieldset>
      <label for="fullName">What is your name?</label>
      <input type="text" name="fullName" id="fullName">

      <label for="email">What is your email?</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email">

      <label for="event">What is your event?</label>
      <input type="text" name="event" id="event">

      <label for="date">What date or date range would you like?</label>
      <input type="text" name="date" id="date">

      <label for="comments">Any additional comments?</label>
      <textarea name="comments" id="comments"></textarea>

      <button class="big-button">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Which is then processed by a php script to log to a database and to send an email out. That php script captures the input value and stores them as a variable.

```
$fullName = $_POST['fullName'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$event = $_POST['event'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
```

If I var_dump, I get NULL. However the URL shows the values.

Comment: You didn't define a `method` for your form, so it's a GET form, and you're using POST... see what the problem might be?

Comment: @MarcB This is a self-answered question.

Comment: @jprofitt: you'd be surprised at how effective slapping someone around with a cluebat can be.

Comment: @MarcB Just mentioning that the OP already knew what the problem/solution was when the question was posted

Comment: I figured it out while writing up the question. Sometimes you have to just step back. Didn't see that it was already answered so figured I'd post it in case it helped someone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is an often overlooked issue and it starts right at the top.

```
<form action="requestdate.php" class="unit-66">
```

Has no method. It should be

```
<form action="requestdate.php" method="post" class="unit-66">
```

Answer (score 2):

Must me

```
<form action="requestdate.php" class="unit-66" method="post">
```

for

```
$_POST['<name>']
```

else it must be

```
<form action="requestdate.php" class="unit-66" method="get">
```

and in php you can get it as

```
$_GET['<name>']
```